# Facebook access token from php to javascript

Tags: php, facebook

I have already implemented logging in with php, now I want to implement payments, however all the tutorials are in javascript, is this possible to send user access token to javascript somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the payment dialog can only be triggered via the JS SDK, as you already mentioned:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/paymentflow/#paydialog

Once you got the `payment_id`, you can use the Graph API to get the details:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/payment